# Where the heck did my wife go?

Tags: fable-3

I married Harriet the Furniture Seller in Brightwall Village. We lived there very happily until she started complaining about our house. I moved her to the nicest house in Brightwall, and still she complained. So I set her up in a nice little house in the Bowerstone Old Quarter. It even had an *indoor* staircase! Harriet the Furniture Seller seemed very happy there.

Then, we destroyed the Old Quarter en route to my becoming Queen. Harriet the Furniture Seller's and my house was not spared from the fiery destruction. But I'm playing through the game as a good guy, so I paid Reaver Industries to repair the Old Quarter. Our house was rebuilt complete with its little plaque with the heart on it, but I can't find Harriet the Furniture Seller anywhere. She's not hanging out in the house, in Bowerstone Market where I usually find her, or anywhere on the streets of the Old Quarter. She's not back in Brightwall. I moved our household to a new house in Bowerstone Market to see if that would free her from some glitch, but she's still nowhere to be found.

Where, oh where, has my poor Harriet the Furniture Seller gone?

**Update:** Louise the Housewife and I are set up very happily in Bowerstone Castle, but not a day goes by that I don't think fondly of my Harriet the Furniture Seller, and miss her dearly.

Comment: I'm sorry you had to find out this way...

Comment: She's visiting a farm, upstate.  She's happy there, and you shouldn't worry about her.  No, you can't go and visit, sorry. :(

Comment: Wow, and I thought Nethack had all the best question titles :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you this, but all the money in Fable [cannot](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110430154340AAsTSnk&ei=O20pT4rSGqK20AHustynAg&usg=AFQjCNE3wxJcFHAH9X2Mcbn5dEVVI_unKA&sig2=z3sNQAe0xP8LiPYVp3kFgw) [bring](http://boards.ign.com/fable/b6152/197137143/p1) [back](http://fable.wikia.com/wiki/Elise) your dear wife from the destruction of the Old Quarter...

Comment: My poor wife!! I guess I have to divorce her even though she's gone to get all the heart stuff to go away then?

Comment: That's what I would do, and with time, maybe you could have a second mariage and be a happy couple once again.

Comment: A new problem! I can't divorce her. Looks like I am doomed to have a ghost wife for eternity.

Comment: welp, at least the game recognizes that you still love her so much. XD