# What irrevertible glitches should I be aware of when playing Fable 3?

Tags: pc, fable-3

The [vanishing wife issue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49224/88) sounds like a serious mood-killer, so one should never move a family to the Bowerstone Old Quarter. What other things should I be aware of so I don't have start over again or cope with such nuisances?

I'm specifically asking about the PC version, where some additional glitch-fixing (e.g. hex editing) may be possible.

Comment: The scope on this question is very broad.  It is easy to imagine the glitches in this game filling a book.

Comment: @DavidB I hope you're overstating... However, as said I'd like to restrict the question to truly gamebreaking ones, i.e. such that the game won't be enjoyable anymore without restarting.

Answer (score 1):

One bug to try to avoid, is when your dog starts to limp as if it got hurt. See [Here](http://fable.wikia.com/wiki/Dog_%28Fable_III%29) for more explanation. If your dog starts to limp, The dog can't help you attack enemies, find digging spots or treasure chests when it starts to limp

Comment: Scars aren't bugs.

Comment: It's not, but it's irreversible.